# Override the my-account.tpl template file when install the module that I have created in prestashop 1.6,

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have created a custom module in prestashop, I just need to Override the `my-account.tpl` template file when I install the module, that module I have created custom. I don't  have any idea how to do that.can somebody help me out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
/* INSTALL */
@copy('../themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/my-account.tpl','../themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/my-account.tplback'); //Backup file
@copy('../modules/NOMDUMODULE/my-account.tpl','../themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/my-account.tpl'); //Install new file

/*DESINSTALL*/
@unlink('../themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/my-account.tpl'); //Delete file
@copy('../themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/my-account.tplback','../themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/my-account.tpl'); //Restor file
```

Regards